# "ENTRYPOINT ["./init.sh"]" in Dockerfile produces "no such file or directory" when using Docker-Compose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Consider the `docker-compose` file :

```
version: '3.0'

volumes:
    data:
        driver: local

networks: 
    simple-network:
        driver: bridge

services:
    postgres:
        container_name: postgres
        image: postgres
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: node-crud
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        ports: 
            - "5432:5432"
        volumes: 
            - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        networks: 
            - simple-network

    api:
        container_name: api
        image: api
        restart: unless-stopped
        build: 
            context: simple-node-api
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports: 
            - "3000:3000"
        environment:
            - NODE_ENV=production
            - DATABASE=node-crud
            - USERNAME=postgres
            - PASSWORD=postgres
            - HOST=postgres
        networks: 
            - simple-network
        depends_on: 
            - postgres
```

With the api's Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /api
COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
COPY init.sh .
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["./init.sh"]
```

And the `init.sh` script :

```
#!/bin/sh
yarn run migrate
yarn run start
```

When I run `docker-compose up` the output is :

```
Creating network "simple-example_simple-network" with driver "bridge"
Creating postgres ... done                                                                                                                                                       Creating api      ... done                                                                                                                                                       Attaching to postgres, api
api         | standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
postgres    |
postgres    | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres    |
postgres    | 2020-11-25 13:35:12.683 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.1 (Debian 13.1-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
postgres    | 2020-11-25 13:35:12.683 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres    | 2020-11-25 13:35:12.684 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres    | 2020-11-25 13:35:12.698 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres    | 2020-11-25 13:35:12.719 UTC [24] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-11-25 13:34:01 UTC
postgres    | 2020-11-25 13:35:12.738 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
api exited with code 1
api exited with code 1
api exited with code 1
api exited with code 1
api exited with code 1
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping api      ... done                                                                                                                                                       Stopping postgres ...
Killing postgres  ...
ERROR: Aborting.
```

I'm working under Windows 10 , why is it producing `no such file or directory` even
though the file exists in the path ?

Comment: Trying to remove "./" and check if the script had execution permission

Comment: Also double-check that the script has Unix line endings.

Comment: Why not use `ENTRYPOINT yarn run migrate &&  yarn run start`? No need init.sh.

Answer (score 0):

Entrypoint should be absolute path.

Try:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/api/init.sh"]
```

Be sure that `/api/init.sh` have the `+x` exec bit set.

Comment: What do you mean by `+x` bit ? how do I set it ?

Comment: `RUN chmod +x /api/init.sh`